# MongoDb Query Filtering with arithmetic expression

Tags: mongodb

i have a query in sql that I wan't to translate into the MongoDb query.

The statement is:

```
select * from TBA where a/b < c/d
```

a,b,c are columns in the table tba and d is a constant

How can I rewrite this statement into the MongoDb query language?
I have a document collection called "TBA" where all documents are stored. Now I want to find out which documents fulfill the condition "a/b < c/d".

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
user12682244

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a calculation using the values stored in the document, you need to use a pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          {$divide: ["$a", "$b"]},
          {$divide: ["$c", d]}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KQNrnlVytsR)